# Problem porting from CentOS 7 to Rocky Linux 8

Tags: c, linux, glibc, glib

I'm porting some code from CentOS7 to Rocky Linux 8.
The code compiles fine, but when I run the exec file I got the following error :

```
   GLib:ERROR:gmain.c:3737:g_main_context_check: assertion failed: (i <= 0 || fds[i - 1].fd < fds[i].fd)
                        Aborted
```

Runnig the gdb with the core file I got these back trace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fb6df8b5a4f in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fb6df888db5 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fb6df56a123 in g_assertion_message.cold ()
   from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fb6df5c320e in g_assertion_message_expr ()
   from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fb6df59b642 in g_main_context_check () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fb6df59bc30 in g_main_context_iterate.isra ()
   from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007fb6df59bdb0 in g_main_context_iteration ()
   from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007fb6e008af08 in MsgCaptureTO ()
   from /axs/lib64/utilmsg-glib2.so
#8  0x00007fb6e008b127 in loop_msg () from /axs/lib64/utilmsg-glib2.so
#9  0x000000000040157e in main ()
(gdb)
```

Debugging the code I found the code that has the problem

```
int ctrlpollDoPoll(unsigned long int difmsg)
{
  int fdpend;

  if(difmsg == 0)
  {
     fdpend = g_main_context_iteration(g_main_context_default(), FALSE);
  }
  else
  {
     if(capture_msg_source == FALSE)
     {
        GSource* source;
        capture_msg_source = TRUE;
        source = g_source_new(&capture_msgs_funcs, sizeof(GSource));
        g_source_set_priority(source, G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT + 1);
        g_source_set_can_recurse(source, TRUE);
        g_source_attach(source, g_main_context_default());

     }
     timeout_max_capture_msgs = difmsg;
     fdpend = g_main_context_iteration(g_main_context_default(), TRUE);
  }
  return fdpend;
}
```

The core occurs in the line

```
fdpend = g_main_context_iteration(g_main_context_default(), TRUE);
```

The core is created and show the message :

```
GLib:ERROR:gmain.c:3737:g_main_context_check: assertion failed: (i <= 0 || fds[i - 1].fd < fds[i].fd)
Aborted
```

Running the process with strace I got these messages :

```
159971 15:15:46 rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=0x7f7784a97de0, sa_mask=[], sa
_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f77844daad0}, NULL, 8) = 0
159971 15:15:46 times({tms_utime=0, tms_stime=0, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 
438007582
159971 15:15:46 poll([{fd=1, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}, {fd=
3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 4, 10000) = 2 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOU
T}, {fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
159971 15:15:46 read(4, "\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
159971 15:15:46 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/charset.alias", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOE
NT (No such file or directory)
159971 15:15:46 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONL
Y) = 6
159971 15:15:46 fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26998, ...}) = 0
159971 15:15:46 mmap(NULL, 26998, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 6, 0) = 0x7f77850e0000
159971 15:15:46 close(6)                = 0
159971 15:15:46 futex(0x7f778484c9a8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
159971 15:15:46 write(2, "**\nGLib:ERROR:gmain.c:3737:g_mai"..., 105) = 105
159971 15:15:46 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
159971 15:15:46 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
159971 15:15:46 getpid()                = 159971
159971 15:15:46 gettid()                = 159971
159971 15:15:46 tgkill(159971, 159971, SIGABRT) = 0
159971 15:15:46 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
159971 15:15:46 --- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=159971, 
si_uid=0} ---
159971 15:15:46 +++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
```

The glib rpm packages installed are :

```
[root@localhost ~]#   rpm -qa|grep glib
dbus-glib-0.110-2.el8.x86_64
glib-networking-2.56.1-1.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
json-glib-1.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
glibc-common-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-2.28-189.1.el8.i686
glib2-2.56.4-158.el8.i686
glib2-2.56.4-158.el8.x86_64
glibc-all-langpacks-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-langpack-br-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-locale-source-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-189.1.el8.x86_64
```

Any help, please ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mcve].  There's not enough information to even begin trying to debug this.

Comment: Just run the code under debugger, assert should drop you to the debugger to inspect the situation.

Comment: It is fairly obvious that the expression returned `true`, so either `i` is less than or equal to `0`, or `fds[i - 1].fd < fds[i].fd`, which would not surprise me. Do you want us to guess what that means?